# Looking for a simple NTP setup for CentOS 7

Tags: centos, ntp

I need to set up an NTP server for testing purposes on a non-internet-connected network, but I am having issues finding a clear-cut example of what to do to get this to work.

This NTP server will be for testing purposes only. None of the systems on the network have any access to the internet at all ... 100% air gap.

I want my development machine (192.168.1.123) to be the NTP server. This is what I have tried:

```
$ sudo yum install ntp
$ sudo systemctl start ntpd
$ sudo systemctl enable ntpd
```

Then I edited my /etc/ntp.conf file:

```
server 192.168.1.123 prefer
restrict 127.0.0.1
driftfile /etc/ntp/drift
broadcastdelay 0.008
```

Then I edited my /etc/ntp/drift file:

```
0.000
```

I made sure that the system's (192.168.1.123) firewall was allowing ntp, then I rebooted the machine. When the machine comes back online and I check `ntpstat` I get this message:

```
unsynchronised
    polling server every 8 s
```

When I run `ntpq -p` I get:

```
remote                 refid    st t when poll reach    delay    offset jitter
==============================================================================
1470-lt-037881   .INIT.         16 u    - 1024    0     0.000     0.000 0.000
```

when I run `netstat -an | grep 123` I get this:

```
udp        0        0 172.16.156.1:123        0.0.0.0:*
udp        0        0 192.168.125.1:123       0.0.0.0:*
udp        0        0 192.168.1.123:123       0.0.0.0:*
udp        0        0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0        0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0        0 xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:123 :::*
udp6       0        0 xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:123 :::*
udp6       0        0 xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:123 :::*
udp6       0        0 ::1:123                 :::*
udp6       0        0 :::123                  :::*
```

I have no idea what `1470-lt-037881` is and the `172.16.156.1` and `192.168.125.1` IP addresses are vmnet8 and vmnet1 (respectively) addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the local clock as preferred server.

```
 server  127.127.1.0
 fudge  127.127.1.0 stratum 10
```

quoting from [basic ntp configuration tldp](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/basic-ntp-config.html) :

> The most basic ntp.conf file will simply list 2 servers, one that it
>   wishes to synchronize with, and a **pseudo IP address** for itself (in
>   this case 127.127.1.0). The pseudo IP is used in case of network
>   problems or if the remote NTP server goes down. NTP will synchronize
>   against itself until the it can start synchronizing with the remote
>   server again. It is recommended that you list at least 2 remote
>   servers that you can synchronize against. One will act as a primary
>   server and the other as a backup.

quoting from [reference clock ntp-faq](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-refclk.htm)

> The LCL is no reference clock in reality; instead it simply refers to
>   the system time on the current machine. Therefore it should never be
>   used, except when the system time is synchronized by some means not
>   visible by xntpd.
>
> On an isolated network one might set the time manually from time to
>   time. Together with a frequency adjustment available as a fudge factor
>   (see the driver's documentation) one may achieve an accuracy of a few
>   seconds per week.

Comment: Is that a typo: `127.127.1.0`?

Comment: i updated the answer.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Now when I run `ntpstat` I get `synchronised to local net at stratum 6 time correct to within 7948 ms polling every 64 seconds`. Is that what it should look like?

Comment: `synchronised to local net at stratum 13 time correct to within 7948 ms polling every 64 seconds`

Comment: take a look at the link i have added.